# Android clipboard manager on api level 8

Tags: android

in my application i want to use clipboard manager, in manifest my min sdk is 8 and for use ClipBoardManager i get this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipData#newPlainText
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipboardManager#setPrimaryClip
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipData#newPlainText
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipboardManager#setPrimaryClip
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipData#newPlainText
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipboardManager#setPrimaryClip
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipboardManager#setPrimaryClip
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.content.ClipData#newPlainText
```

My code:

```
case 3:
    String n1 = numbers_list.getText ().toString ();
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) G.context.getSystemService(G.context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(n1);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) G.context.getSystemService(G.context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip_data = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText(
        "TSMS", n1);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip_data);
    }
    numbers_list.setText ( "" );
    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add suppress warnings in your code :

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

Use the code below :

```
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(n1);
} else {
    android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    android.content.ClipData clip_data = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText(
    context.getResources().getString(
    R.string.message), n1);
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip_data);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please add suppress warnings above your onCreate method